# JSP Post equivalent

Tags: forms, jsp

I'm new to `JSP` and this is quite confusing to me. 
In `Php` I can do something like this :

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="LoginFormAction.php">
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="username" SIZE="16">
```

and then use this to get what was in the `TextBox` :

```
$_POST['username'];
```

The current equivalent I have in `Jsp` is :

```
 <form action="checkLogin.jsp">
 <input name="username" size=15 type="text" />
```

How can I get what is in the `TextBox` once I submit my form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use: request.getParameter("username").toString()